# annoying issue with nodeJS while running "npm install"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy

what's the reason about this issue while running "npm install" ?

after running `npm install` - I'm getting tons of errors

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586 
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" 
npm ERR! node v4.4.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8 
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo

npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ex-proxy.com ex-proxy.com:8080
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity. 
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the 
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mo7sn\Desktop\Angular2-GettingStarted-master\APM - Start\npm-debug.log
```

my OS is windows 10

- this is a screenshot :
  [image]
  this question may be duplicated . but I tried most of answers and not works for me

Comment: Sounds like you're running behind a proxy `ENOTFOUND ex-proxy.com`, have you configured it for NPM?

Comment: I don't understand , I am a bit new to nodeJS - just tell me the simple steps

Comment: Are you in a country that restricts access to certain websites? As far as I can see, this isn't a node issue, just a network issue.

Comment: Have you done what it asks? `npm help config`?

Comment: it just opened a static html docs page

Comment: @ChrisG No - some months ago it worked with me in the same country - but in different OS,laptop

Comment: `npm help config` will tell you the simple steps you need to take.it's like SO, but in your console, how awesome is that!

Comment: No - it open a static html docs page - talking about -> Manage the npm configuration files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it

this problem happened because

1. Visual Studio not installed
2. Some issues with internet connection

Answer (score 1):

use

c:>npm cache clean

c:>npm delete proxy

and try again

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot is not the same as what you wrote in your question.

In the question you quote:

```
npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ex-proxy.com ex-proxy.com:8080
```

What's vsible in the screenshot is:

```
npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npms.org registry.npms.org:80
```

It should be registry.npmjs.org and not registry.npms.org.

Compare:

- http://registry.npms.org/
- http://registry.npmjs.org/

If you're using a proxy then you should configure it properly. If you can access https://registry.npmjs.org/ from your computer directly and you can `ping registry.npmjs.org` then you should not need a proxy.

Comment: I can access and ping it well (it's a JSON file) , I edited it to npmjs
 - I still get error - check : http://i.imgur.com/gnkOrkP.png